# Group rows under condition, get all results

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am working on a facebook like notification system. I want to group data, when the Entity ID and type of operation (labeled CUD) are the same. So from this:

```
+----+-----------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id | display_name    | name   | surname    | avatar | type      | last_check          | redirect            | created             | cud | notif_culprit | entity_id |
+----+-----------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+---------------+-----------+
| 45 |                 | Julie  | Opletalová |        | character | Character:edit, 316 | Character:edit, 316 | 2018-02-03 00:55:04 |   2 |             5 |       316 |
| 52 | juliina postava | Julie  | Opletalová |        | character | Character:edit, 325 | Character:edit, 325 | 2018-02-03 01:22:47 |   1 |             5 |       325 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-03 23:15:39 |   2 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-03 23:51:39 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-03 23:57:23 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-04 00:05:45 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-04 00:06:02 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-04 00:06:16 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-04 00:23:50 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-04 00:30:06 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-04 00:30:36 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
+----+-----------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+---------------+-----------+
```

I would like to have

```
+----+-----------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id | display_name    | name   | surname    | avatar | type      | last_check          | redirect            | created             | cud | notif_culprit | entity_id |
+----+-----------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+---------------+-----------+
| 45 |                 | Julie  | Opletalová |        | character | Character:edit, 316 | Character:edit, 316 | 2018-02-03 00:55:04 |   2 |             5 |       316 |
| 52 | juliina postava | Julie  | Opletalová |        | character | Character:edit, 325 | Character:edit, 325 | 2018-02-03 01:22:47 |   1 |             5 |       325 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-03 23:15:39 |   2 |             3 |       326 |
| 62 | veveho postava  | Martin | Nezamysl   |        | character | Character:edit, 326 | Character:edit, 326 | 2018-02-03 23:51:39 |   3 |             3 |       326 |
```

I know about "having" command in mysql, so I could use group by with having specifying type. But I was able to do that with only one type (CUD). I need to display all types.

Here is SqlFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a8361/1

Comment: What do you really mean by you need to display all types?

Comment: is it all columns?

Comment: How do you decide wich line you keep ?

Comment: @cdaiga I will try to explain by example. Let's have two rows, they both have same entity id and CUD, so I want to group them. Another two also has same CUD and entity id (but different than previous ones) so I want to group them as well. At the end I want to see all groups.

Comment: @DanielE. Thats a good question, I will be using data of all grouped rows anyway (for example names).

Btw. how does mysql choose row during normal grouping?

Comment: Please edit clarifications into posts, not comments. Also put relevant fiddle content in your post not just as a link. Also please don't just give an input & its output, use enough words, phrases & sentences to clearly explain how they are related, not just short summarizing phrases. Show what parts you have been able to code.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to group your result by the id, and cud.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, cud;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a8361/7)

Comment: I tought this will group all by entity Id and then by cud. What if it's the same entity ID and different CUD? I dont want it to be grouped.

Comment: @Kudlas Did you check the fiddle? This answer does what you asked for.

Comment: I rolled back the edit, I mistakenly approved it. The code works as it stands. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes I have checked the fiddle and in this one case it works and I am just asking if it works In all scenarios I described in original question.

Comment: @Kudlas That is for you to tell. We are not in your head, neither can we guess every use cases you are faced with. If you realize you did not described correctly what you need, you can add details (without changing too much) to your original question. Otherwise, this should be an accepted answer to the problem you described.